# What is referencing in Python (applied to lists, specifically)?

Tags: python

I started to learn python and encountered something strange and wanted to ask about it.

Below is the coding and I highlighted the part of the function I have a question about.

At the end of the function `def add_attraction(destination, attraction)`, `return` alone is written not specifying what value it is returning. But it still returns the value stored in variable `attractions_for_destination`. How could this be?

To put it differently, how I understand is `attractions_for_destination = attractions[destination_index]` this code stores the value of `attractions[destination_index]` in the newly made `attractions_for_destination` variable. And through`attractions_for_destination.append(attraction)`, this code adds a change to the newly made
variable. But in the end what is changed is the `attractions` variable.
In short, changes are added to `attractions_for_destination` but I don’t understand how `attractions` are also changed.

I asked this question somewhere else on the internet and the someone helped me and mentioned something about referencing. I don't actually get it, because still a value is appended to `attractions_for_destination` variable and not `attractions` variable, but the console shows that `attractions` variable is appended. Can someone clarify this for me?

```
destinations = ["Paris, France", 
"Shanghai, China", "Los Angeles, USA", "Sao Paulo, Brazil", "Cairo, Egypt"]

test_traveler = ['Erin Wilkes', 'Shanghai, China', ['historical site', 'art']]

#destination index
destination_index = 0
def get_destination_index(destination):
  destination_index = destinations.index(destination)
  return destination_index

#traveler current destination
def get_traveler_location(traveler):
  traveler_destination = traveler[1]
  traveler_destination_index = get_destination_index(traveler_destination)
  return traveler_destination_index

#finding traveler current destination index
test_destination_index = get_traveler_location(test_traveler)

attractions = [[] for destination in destinations]

def add_attraction(destination, attraction):
  try:
    destination_index = get_destination_index(destination)
  except ValueError:
    return 
  ***attractions_for_destination = attractions[destination_index]
  attractions_for_destination.append(attraction)
  return*** 

add_attraction("Los Angeles, USA", ['venice Beach' , ['beach']]) 

print(attractions)
```

Comment: As a side note, defining functions to look up the index of some piece of data and passing around indices like this makes this some piece of ugly coding. The data structure is certainly not the right one for the problem at hand, and I would definitely not recommend this as learning material.

Comment: I agree completely with @ThierryLathuille and have reflected this (also as an aside) in the answer I wrote. There must be many good examples where lists of lists are appropriate to solve a problem, so it is a shame that the learning material has chosen a contrived example.

Answer (score 3):

`attractions` is a list of lists.

In the assignment statement:

```
attractions_for_destination = attractions[destination_index]
```

This associates the name `attractions_for_destination` with one of the inner lists that are elements of the `attractions` list.  That is to say, it does not make a copy of it, but rather, the name `attractions_for_destination` now refers to exactly the same list object in memory.  So when that list is modified (in this case, by calling its `append` method), the modified value can be seen, regardless of which reference to the list is used to access it.  In particular, there is also still a reference to the same list as an element of the `attractions` list, so the modified value of the sub-list is seen when you do `print(attractions)`.

The two lines which you highlighted have a similar overall effect to doing simply:

```
    attractions[destination_index].append(attraction)
```

---

Aside from answering the direct question, I would also add that in this code, having a list in the same order as another list (in this case `attractions` and `destinations`) is a poor choice of data type, and it would be better to use a dictionary.  For example:

```
attractions = dict((destination, []) for destination in destinations)

def add_attraction(destination, attraction):
    try:
        attractions[destination].append(attraction)
    except KeyError:
        return
```